# Realm: live updates of constant values

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm using SwiftRealm 2.03 and do not understand the magic how constant data (even metadata) gets updated if the data in realm changes...

Here an example:

```
 private func closePastExistingTravelTimes(){

        let travelTimes = fetchTravelTimes(onlyNotClosedTravelTimes: true)

        guard travelTimes.count > 1 else {
            return
        }

        let numberOfTravelTimes = travelTimes.count

        for index in 0..<numberOfTravelTimes-2{

            print("index:\(index) count:\(travelTimes.count)")

            try! realm.write {
                let travelTime = travelTimes[index]
                travelTime.travelPhaseIsClosed = true
                realm.add(travelTime, update: true)
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm loading data in the beginning and store them in an constant.
Then I iterate over the items and change the condition of the query so that the fetched data would change if I would query again. But I don't. What even is more suprising that the constant numberOfTravelTimes is even adjusted as you can see below in the log.

```
index:0 count:5
index:1 count:4
index:2 count:3
index:3 count:2 --> BAM - Exception
```

What is happening here? How can I be save in my example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Realm `Results` objects are live](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#auto-updating-results), meaning if you update an object in such a way that it no longer conforms to a `Results` query, the `Results` object will update to exclude it. This means you need to be careful when you base a `for` loop off a `Results` object, since if the `Results` object mutates in the middle of the loop, you'll end up with an exception.

Normally, the easiest, but not the most elegant way to mitigate this is to copy all of the Realm objects in a `Results` object to a static array so it won't mutate during the loop.

In this particular case however, it would be more appropriate to just enclose the entire `for` loop inside the Realm write transaction. This is generally best practice (Since it's best to batch as many Realm writes into as few write transactions as possible), but in this case, it will have the added advantage of not updating the contents of the `Results` object until after you're done with it.

```
try! realm.write { // Open the Realm write transaction outside of the loop
    for index in 0..<numberOfTravelTimes-2 {
        print("index:\(index) count:\(travelTimes.count)")

        let travelTime = travelTimes[index]
        travelTime.travelPhaseIsClosed = true
        realm.add(travelTime, update: true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate your results in reverse order.

```
for index in (0 ..<numberOfTravelTimes-1).reverse()
```

See if it helps

Comment: I think the best way is to copy it to an array and use this for iteration. I must be aware that Results<T> is a magic container that keeps itself up to date.

Comment: This was handled later in Realm-Java by "delaying synchronization to the next event loop", apparently Realm-Swift didn't hack the way the Realm-Core works.

Comment: What happens is that while you're in a transaction, you always see the latest version of the Realm, this also means that as elements in the Realm change, this alters the Results returned by the query in real time. This issue can be worked around by iterating the result set backwards.